# how to use jquery append & appendTo

Tags: jquery, firefox

I was trying to use `append` to put the block content onto then bottom of the body and display with absolute position, but when displayed an input checkbox becomes non-clickable on Firefox.

What is the problem?

js:

```
var box = $('#subbox');
box.css('top',  200);
box.css('left', 300);     
$(document.body).append(box);
```

HTML:

```
  <div id="Subbox" class="subbox">
    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked"> 
  </div>
```

css:

```
  .subbox {
position:absolute !important;
z-index: 5 !important;
background-color: #eee;
padding: 5px;
margin:0px;
margin-top:0px; 
border:1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't fully understand your question (what does "crackable" mean?) I will go for the obvious things to mention here.

First of all, I'd like to say that in general, it's a bad idea to use the same name for IDs and class names in the same document.  Even with one of them having a capital letter, it's just not very nice.

Secondly, the HTML is invalid, because the `INPUT` tag has no ending.  Always make sure the HTML is valid (or at least not entirely broken) before trying anything else.

Comment: i meant clickable. sorry for typo.

Answer (score 1):

Are you generating `<div id="Subbox" />` and its contents in JavaScript?

If I've understood correctly, are you looking for something like this?

```
$(function() {

    var cssObject = { top: 200, left: 300 }

    $('<div id="Subbox" class="subbox">')
        .append('<input type="checkbox" checked="checked"/>')
        .css(cssObject)
        .appendTo(document.body);

});
```

[Working Demo here](http://jsbin.com/uboxu) (add **/edit** to the URL to edit the demo)

Tested in Firefox 3.0.8 and IE6 and it works correctly.